# Increasing Volume Group Size without new Disk

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm, fdisk

On my server (RHEL8) running on vCenter, I have a Volume Group that consists of 1 Disk.

I want to increase the Volume Group size without adding a secondary virtual Disk in vCenter.

Old Disk size: 50 GB
New Disk size: 400 GB

How can I extend the VG to use the whole 400 GB of space on the extended virtual Disk?

Than you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you search for is `pvresize`. If you exec:

```
pvresize /dev/sda
```

this should extend the PV to the full size of full size of disk `/dev/sda`

If you use partition (`/dev/sda1` for example) you should first extend the partition and then exec the above command (directing to the partition, not disk)

Comment: After Doing pvresize /dev/sda and lvresize -r -l +100%FREE /dev/vg_xx/lv_xx it worked, thank you